# asp.Net MVC 3 Routing Based on Number of Segments

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I realize the concept of having routing defined and executed in a specific order but I have the following routes defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Image",                                        
            "Image/{action}/{width}/{height}/{file}",       
            new { controller = "Image", action = "Thumbnail", width = 250, height = 250 }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
           "GetCampaignsByCampaignType",
           "Endorsement/GetCampaignsByCampaignType/{campaignType}",
           new { controller = "Endorsement", action = "GetCampaignsByCampaignType" }
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "Help",
            "Help",
            new { controller = "Help", action = "Contact" } 
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "Campaigns",
            "Campaigns",
            new { controller = "Endorsement", action = "Campaigns" } 
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "Campaign",
            "{campaignUrlName}",
            new { controller = "Endorsement", action = "GetCampaign" }
        );
```

The question has to do with the bottom 2 routes. I have campaigns like /Summer, /Winter, /Some-other-name where I have hundreds of these and would like not to hard-code them in. I also have other routes that I want to be hit like /Campaign/Account, /Help/Me/Please (where there are more than one segment /1/2 or /1/2/3)

What is the proper order or definition to allow me to have /1 go to the last route defined above and /1/2 or /1/2/3 go the default {controller}/{action}/{id}

Currently, both scenarios go to the default route {controller}/{action}/{id} including /1. If I reverse them, then /1 works but /1/2 or /1/2/3 does not go to the default routing.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution via regex:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new { action = @"\w*" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Campaign",
            "{campaignUrlName}",
            new { controller = "Endorsement", action = "GetCampaign" },
            new { campaignUrlName = @"^([a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z_-]*[\w_-]*[\S]$|^([a-zA-Z])[0-9_-]*[\S]$|^[a-zA-Z]*[\S]$" }
        );
```

This way action is required which defaults to two segments /1/2 (perfect) and never catches any single segment urls and the last route gets hit after it passes all others and simply makes sure that it contains proper characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your default route will always override your campaign route, because there are defaults for the controller and method.  So /Winter will get interpreted as "WinterController" (which doesn't exist) with the Default Index (which also doesn't exist), so you will get a 404.

You will have to define specific routes for /Winter and /Summer, etc.. and place them before the default.

Comment: That's the whole point is I have hundreds if not thousands of these. I cannot hard-code these. There has to be a better way. Will need to find out what that is. Thank you for your reply though. Just not willing to be defeated yet.

Comment: Well, there are always other ways.  You could write your own route handler that looks up campaigns in a database, and if it doesn't find them, then calls the default route.

Comment: I think a custom constraint is the way to go utilizing regex. Just have to figure out what that is. This way no need for db calls.

Comment: @gsogoly - A custom constraint won't help you, because you still can't tell the difference between a campaign and a default request.  You will always get either one or the other.  The only way to have both is to have a lookup of some kind to see what valid campaigns are.